# How to chain middlewares using routers

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express 4.0 and I'm having trouble to chain middlewares. I have 2 routers : a job router and a recruiter router.
Everything works fine at the moment ( I can use CRUDs on both of these routers) but I'd like the POST method for a job to call a method withing the recruiter router and I don't know to achieve this.

router/recruiter.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET recruiters listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var recruiters = [];
    //get recruiters
        res.json(recruiters);
});

function(err, req, res, next) {
   console.info("pseudo code for a function I'd like to call in the job.js file");
});

module.exports = router;
```

router/job.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var uuid = require('uuid4');
var router = express.Router();

var jobs = [];

/* GET job listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    jobs = [];
    //get jobs
    res.json(jobs);
});

/* add jobs . */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.info('add job', req.body);

    var body = req.body;
    //I omit the parts where I check the req and save the object


    //At the moment I do this but I'd like to call a method within the recruiter router before sending the json back to the client.
    res.json({'jobs': []});
});

module.exports = router;
```

and here are the relevant parts in the app.js :

```
var job = require('./routes/job');
var recruiter = require('./routes/recruiter');

app.use('/job', job);
app.use('/recruiter', recruiter);
```

Comment: Put the code you want to call into its own function and then just call that function from two places.  You don't need to use the Express infrastructure to share common code among two routes.  Just use plain JS programming techniques to share common code.

Comment: What you describe was my first implementation but I figured out that there must be a more "express" way to do this ?

Comment: For some unknown reason, people get trapped into thinking that sharing code should be done in an Express way and that's the only way to do things.  I know the feeling as I've seen it in other people posting here and occasionally when writing my own code.  But, just putting common code in a named function and calling it from two places is the generic way to solve this and Express doesn't really offer a better replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comment into an answer...

Express does not offer any special way to share code among multiple routes.  If you want the code always executed before your route handler, you can, of course, use a common middleware function.

But, if your code sharing case is that you just want two or more routes to be able to execute some common code from within their route implementations, then this is really just a plain Javascript issue.  You put the common code into a shared function and you call that function from two or more routes.  In other words, you just share code among routes that same way you share code among any other Javascript functions.  Express doesn't require anything special in this regard.  Do it that way you always do it in Javascript.

It is fairly common that people coding in Express get caught up in the way you structure your code for Express and somehow forget that you can still use regular shared, common functions to share code (I've seen many people caught by this) - expecting their to be an "Express" way to share code.  There isn't.  Just do the normal Javascript method of sharing common code by creating a function with the common code in it and calling it from more than one place.